# Check is vibration with ring mode enabled in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-audiomanager

Trying to detect vibration and ringing simultaneously using the code not its not working. Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING is not working and always returning 0.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int mode = am.getRingerMode();

        switch (mode)
        {

            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:

                if ((1 == Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING, 0))) {
                    // code here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== ring + vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                } else {
                    // code here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== ring + no vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                break;

            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== in silent mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                break;

            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "=== in vibrate mode ===", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                break;
        }
```

Thanks in advance :)